# exception handling in parentheses matching using stacks in java

Tags: java, exception, stack

I am trying to write a program that checks for parentheses matching using stacks.This is my ArrayStack class.

```
public class ArrayStack{ 
    private final int DEFAULT_SIZE=10;
    public int tos;
    Object[] array;
    public ArrayStack(){
        array   =new Object[DEFAULT_SIZE];
            tos=-1;
    }
    public void push(Object e)throws OverFlowException{
        if (isFull()){
            throw new OverFlowException("OverFlow");
        }
        else{
            array[tos+1]=e;
            tos++;
        }
    }
    public Object topAndpop() throws EmptyStackException{
    Object returnPop;
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyStackException("Stack empty");
        else{ 
            returnPop=top();
            pop();
            }
        return returnPop;
    }   
    public void pop() throws EmptyStackException{
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyStackException("Stack empty");
        else
            tos--;
    }
    public Object top() throws EmptyStackException{
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyStackException("Stack empty");
        else
            return array[tos];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return tos==-1;
    }


    public boolean isFull(){
        if(tos==array.length)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public void makeEmpty() throws EmptyStackException{

        while (tos>=0){
            if (isEmpty())
                throw new EmptyStackException("Stack empty");
            else
                pop();
        }
    }
    public void print(){
        for (int i=0;i<=tos;i++){
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }

public static void main (String args[]) throws EmptyStackException,OverFlowException {
    ArrayStack newStack=new ArrayStack();
    newStack.push("S");

    newStack.push("apple");
    newStack.push("D");
    newStack.topAndpop();
    newStack.push("P");

    newStack.print();

}

}
```

And this is my matching class.

```
public class Matching{
    ArrayStack match_Stack=new ArrayStack();
    Object popped;
    Object[] array_match={"{","}"};
    public boolean matching() {
        for(int i=0;i< array_match.length;i++){
            if (array_match[i]=="{" || array_match[i]=="[" ||array_match[i]=="(" )
                match_Stack.push(array_match[i]);
             if(array_match[i]=="}" || array_match[i]=="]" || array_match[i]==")"){
                if (match_Stack.isEmpty())
                    return false;
                if  (match_Stack.topAndpop()==array_match[i]);
                    return true;
            }

        }   
    if (match_Stack.isEmpty())
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
    }
    public static void main (String args[]) throws EmptyStackException,OverFlowException {
    }

}
```

This is EmptyStackException class :

```
public class EmptyStackException extends Exception{
        public EmptyStackException(){
            super();
        }
        public EmptyStackException(String s){
            super(s);

        }
        public void print(){
            System.out.println("OverFlow");
        }
}
```

But the problem is when I compile matching I get an error as **unreported exception EmptyStackException.must be caught or declared to be thrown.**
I think the problem is with exceptions which I don't have a good knowledge of.I am stuck here for days and because of this exception issue I am unable to study the rest of data structures.  So any help on how I can fix this and run this would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Then, how about googling for "Java tutorial exceptions", and reading what you get? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: Then you should be able to fix your problem. Is EmptyStackException a checked exception? Then does it have to be declared by an method throwing it using the `throws` keyword? And do you do it in your matching() method? Re-read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should read a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) about exceptions and work it through completely. This way you will get a better understanding of exceptions.

Your problem is the method `Matching.matching()`. You are using the methods `ArrayStack.push(Object)` and `ArrayStack.topAndpop()` in the method's implementation. But these methods are declared to (potentially) throw an `EmptyStackException`.

Your `matching` method does not deal with that exception. *The exception must be either caught or thrown.* This is what the compiler does tell you. So for a first coming-through declare the method as

```
public boolean matching() throws EmptyStackException
```

Comment: I thought  because exceptions occur at push() and topAndpop() methods and there I have thrown them I don't have to do anything in Matching class.

Comment: First, you must differ between _throwing_ an exception in the code and _declaring_ an exception in a method's signature. Second, you should learn about the difference between checked and unchecked exceptions (and errors). Third, you must learn what to do when a code block declares to throw an exception (which might actually not be thrown). Really, read the tutorial.

Comment: though I read  the article I didn't understand clearly how exceptions work.I'll have to read it again.Thanks for the answers